# Implementing CRC16 efficiently

Tags: crc, crc16

I got a program that I know will run only on very specific hardware, so I started using crc32 as supplied by the SSE4.2 instruction set, but now I need crc16 for a different purpose. Is there a way to coax the hardware to give me crc16 with the same performance as SSE's crc32?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the PCLMULQDQ instruction, you can use that to make a fast CRC.  Though not quite as fast as the crc32 instruction.

Alternatively, a poor man's check value could be the low 16 bits of the result of crc32.

Comment: How much weaker would taking the first half of crc32 be? I know that crc is not a uniform hash function, so it is not optimal to do that. Edit: Perhaps xor'ing the two halves would give a more uniform result?

Comment: It depends on your application.  Half of a crc32 would be weaker than a crc16 if you're trying to detect a very small number of bit flips.  If the error source has a larger impact, then the two will be about equivalent.  In that case, xoring the two halves wouldn't make any difference, since the source bits are already well mixed in the low half.  For the small number of bit errors case, xoring might help.  I'm not sure.